# sklearn model and fit for a list

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I have 2 arrays x and y which are :

```
x=    [['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], ['3', '6', '9', '12', '24'], 
       ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], ['3', '6', '9', '12', '24'], 
       ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], ['3', '6', '9', '12', '24'], 
       ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], ['3', '6', '9', '12', '24'], 
       ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], ['3', '6', '9', '12', '24'], 
       ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], ['3', '6', '9', '12', '24'], 
       ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], ['3', '6', '9', '12', '24']]


y=    [['2', '4', '6', '8', '10\n'], ['6', '12', '18', '24', '48\n'],
       ['2', '4', '6', '8', '10\n'], ['6', '12', '18', '24', '48\n'], 
       ['2', '4', '6', '8', '10\n'], ['6', '12', '18', '24', '48\n'], 
       ['2', '4', '6', '8', '10\n'], ['6', '12', '18', '24', '48\n'], 
       ['2', '4', '6', '8', '10\n'], ['6', '12', '18', '24', '48\n'], 
       ['2', '4', '6', '8', '10\n'], ['6', '12', '18', '24', '48\n'], 
       ['2', '4', '6', '8', '10\n'], ['6', '12', '18', '24', '48']]
```

trying to get the prediction by:

```
model.fit(array(x),array(y))

model.predict(array(x[10]))
```

getting Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 29, in <module>
    model.predict(array(x[10]))
  File "C:\U.....\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py", line 256, in predict
    return self._decision_function(X)
  File "C:\U....\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py", line 239, in _decision_function
    X = check_array(X, accept_sparse=['csr', 'csc', 'coo'])
  File "C:....\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 441, in check_array
    "if it contains a single sample.".format(array))
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=['1' '2' '3' '4' '5'].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1)
```

so I am looking for linear regression for a model where the input is a array and output is also array ..

can you please correct me what I am missing

Comment: doesn't work `fit(x, y)` ?

Comment: it seems `predict()` needs 2-dimensional array but `x[10]` is single row - it means 1-dimensional array. Did you try to use `[x[10]]` ?

Comment: how can I make it for 1 dimension array ?yes I tried x[10] also did not work

Comment: you have to add external `[ ]` to create 2-dimensional list - `[x[10]]`

Comment: You probably want to convert your data from strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace the predict() line in your code with this:

```
import numpy as np
model.predict(np.array(x[10], dtype=np.int32).reshape(1,-1))
```

The error message says that you need to provide a 2-d array of X to predict() method. 
Currently x[10] will give a single dimension array:

```
[1 2 3 4 5]
```

But we need to do it like:

```
[[1 2 3 4 5]]
```

So according to the hint in error message you can reshape the data to have 1 row and multiple columns. This is achieved by reshape(1,-1).

Or else as stated in the comments by @furas, just wrap your data into a list again like this:

```
model.predict([array(x[10])])
```

Comment: Thank you Vivek this works, why is it taking 2by 2 matric even I declared as 1 by1 matrix? is it the default value it takes. also for a case like this how can I get the formula. if it is a 1by 1 we can have the formula as y=mx+c. but for a one dimensional how can I get the formula